# Why does choosing the 'Windows Ink' tablet API mean I can't navigate in the viewport using my stylus?

Tags: customization, navigation

I'm new in Blender, so I have some problems working with "Grease Pencil".

Obviously when you use a graphic tablet with "Grease Pencil", to achieve good smooth curvature of strokes you better switch to the "Windows Ink" in the "Input" tab of the "Blender Preferences" settings (other "Tablet API"s as "Automatic" & "Wintab" don't give good results. Basically they produce a jagged curved strokes). Below I posted some examples.

[image: Stroke examples]

But when I dealing with "Windows Ink", besides smooth strokes, I can't use almost all interactive viewport navigation tools and right click menus & settings of brushes through the stilus. My stilus is ordinarily like other modern stiluses with two buttons and I assigned to these two buttons the functions corresponding to the right mouse button and middle mouse button. Instead I have to use icons for navigating that are not comfortable or through the mouse itself.

As I say, this problem comes out only when using "Windows Ink". Other "Tablet API"s don't cause issues with viewport navigation and right clicking.

Comment: The issue with the side buttons is being worked on, see [T75566](https://developer.blender.org/T75566).

Comment: Thank You! I'm reading it for the solution right now)